# How to, using image as button to set a value of a field OnSelect

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a PowerApp associated with a SharePoint list access through Edit Form in list from SharePoint Online. I have an image I would like to use as a button. When said button is clicked I want to set a value in the list to update the list value.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a form connecting to SharePoint, do the following:

1. Use the OnSelect function of image control to set a variable value. Image control documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-image).
2. [Unlock the data card from the form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/working-with-cards), which value should be changed be the image.
3. Set the default property of the unlocked datacard to be the variable.

Happy building!